# Why do I get a segmentation fault accessing a struct?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, header, segmentation-fault

**Edit**: added the rest of my code so it's easier to see

I'm receiving a segmentation fault when trying to access certain values of a struct in a header file.

Here's courses.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structs.h"

void createStudents () {
  int random, i;

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    students[i].firstName = firstName[i];
    students[i].lastName = lastName[i];
    random = 10000 + rand() % 89999;
    students[i].num.studentNum = random;
    printf("%d - %s, %s \n", students[i].num.studentNum, students[i].lastName, students[i].firstName);
  }
}

void createCourses () {
  int numbers[999];
  int numbersLeft = 999;
  char courseCode[512];
  char courseCode1[512];
  char courseCode2[512];
  int numCourses = 3;
  int random, i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
    numbers[i] = i;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    random = rand() % numbersLeft;
    if (random < 10) {
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS00%d", random);
      courses[0].cCode = courseCode;
    }
    else if (random < 100 && random > 9) {
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS0%d", random);
      courses[0].cCode = courseCode;
    }
    else if (random > 99){
      snprintf(courseCode, sizeof courseCode, "CS%d", random);
      courses[0].cCode = courseCode;
    }
    courses[0].cName = courseName[0];
    courses[0].cDescription = courseDescription[0];

    numbers[random] = numbers[numbersLeft-1];
    numbersLeft--;

    random = 4 + rand() % 4;
    courses[0].maxRegister = random;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    random = rand() % numbersLeft;
    if (random < 10) {
      snprintf(courseCode1, sizeof courseCode1, "CS00%d", random);
      courses[1].cCode = courseCode1;
    }
    else if (random < 100 && random > 9) {
      snprintf(courseCode1, sizeof courseCode1, "CS0%d", random);
      courses[1].cCode = courseCode1;
    }
    else if (random > 99){
      snprintf(courseCode1, sizeof courseCode1, "CS%d", random);
      courses[1].cCode = courseCode1;
    }
    courses[1].cName = courseName[1];
    courses[1].cDescription = courseDescription[1];

    numbers[random] = numbers[numbersLeft-1];
    numbersLeft--;

    random = 4 + rand() % 4;
    courses[1].maxRegister = random;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    random = rand() % numbersLeft;
    if (random < 10) {
      snprintf(courseCode2, sizeof courseCode2, "CS00%d", random);
      courses[2].cCode = courseCode2;
    }
    else if (random < 100 && random > 9) {
      snprintf(courseCode2, sizeof courseCode2, "CS0%d", random);
      courses[2].cCode = courseCode2;
    }
    else if (random > 99){
      snprintf(courseCode2, sizeof courseCode2, "CS%d", random);
      courses[2].cCode = courseCode2;
    }
    courses[2].cName = courseName[2];
    courses[2].cDescription = courseDescription[2];

    numbers[random] = numbers[numbersLeft-1];
    numbersLeft--;

    random = 4 + rand() % 4;
    courses[2].maxRegister = random;
  }
}

void regiserStudents () {
  int checkSum = 0, checkSum1 = 0, checkTemp = 0, count0 = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
  int wCount0 = 0, wCount1 = 0, wCount2 = 0;
  int v, i, j, random, max0, max1, max2;
  max0 = courses[0].maxRegister;
  max1 = courses[1].maxRegister;
  max2 = courses[2].maxRegister;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    checkTemp = count0;

    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
      random = rand() % 3;
      if (random == 0) {
        if (count0 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count0] = &students[j];
          count0++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[0].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else if (count0 == max0) {
              courses[random].waitlisted[count0] = &students[j];
              wCount0++;
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count0] = &students[j];
              count0++;
            }
          /*}*/
          }
        }
      }
      if (random == 1) {
        if (count1 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count1] = &students[j];
          count1++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[1].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else if (count1 == max1) {
              courses[random].waitlisted[count1] = &students[j];
              wCount1++;
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count1] = &students[j];
              count1++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (random == 2) {
        if (count2 == 0) {
          courses[random].registered[count2] = &students[j];
          count2++;
        }
        else {
          checkSum1 = students[j].num.studentNum;

          for (v = 0; v < checkTemp; v++) {
            checkSum = courses[2].registered[v]->num.studentNum;
            if (checkSum == checkSum1) {
              /*Do Nothing*/
            }
            else if (count2 == max2) {
              courses[random].waitlisted[count2] = &students[j];
              wCount2++;
            }
            else {
              courses[random].registered[count2] = &students[j];
              count2++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  courses[0].studentRegistered = count0;
  courses[1].studentRegistered = count1;
  courses[2].studentRegistered = count2;

  courses[0].studentWaitlisted = wCount0;
  courses[1].studentWaitlisted = wCount1;
  courses[2].studentWaitlisted = wCount2;
}

void printCourses () {
  int i;
  printf("\n%s - %s: %s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[0].cCode, courses[0].cName, courses[0].cDescription, courses[0].studentRegistered, courses[0].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[0].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("* %d - %s, %s \n", courses[0].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[0].registered[i]->lastName, courses[0].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
  printf("Waitlisted Students (%d)", courses[0].studentWaitlisted);
  if (courses[0].studentWaitlisted == 0) {
    printf("\n");
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < courses[0].studentWaitlisted; i++) {
      printf("* %d - %s, %s \n", courses[0].waitlisted[i]->num.studentNum, courses[0].waitlisted[i]->lastName, courses[0].waitlisted[i]->firstName);
    }
  }

  printf("\n%s - %s: %s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[1].cCode, courses[1].cName, courses[1].cDescription, courses[1].studentRegistered, courses[1].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[1].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("* %d - %s, %s \n", courses[1].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[1].registered[i]->lastName, courses[1].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
  printf("\n%s - %s: %s\nRegistered Students (%d/%d):\n", courses[2].cCode, courses[2].cName, courses[2].cDescription, courses[2].studentRegistered, courses[2].maxRegister);

  for (i = 0; i < courses[2].studentRegistered; i++) {
    printf("* %d - %s, %s \n", courses[2].registered[i]->num.studentNum, courses[2].registered[i]->lastName, courses[2].registered[i]->firstName);
  }
}
```

And here's my header file

structs.h

```
#ifndef STRUCTS_H_
#define STRUCTS_H_

char *firstName[] = {
  "Emma", "Liam", "Olivia",
  "Noah", "Ava", "Logan",
  "Sophia", "Lucas", "Isabella",
  "Mason", "Shaylyn", "Jack"
};

char *lastName[] = {
  "Smith", "Johnson", "Williams",
  "Brown", "Jones", "Miller",
  "Davis", "Garcia", "Rodriguez",
  "Wilson", "Seguin", "Loveday"
};

typedef struct{
  int studentNum;
}studentNumber;

typedef struct{
  char *firstName;
  char *lastName;
  studentNumber num;
}studentID;

studentID students[12];

char *courseName[] = {"Web Programming", "Technical Communication", "Processor Architecture"};
char *courseDescription[] = {"Learn the language of HTML, and how to create websites.", "Learn the essentials of communication skills, and how to apply them on the job.", "Learn the basics of circuits and Machine Language coding."};

typedef struct {
  int maxRegister;
  char *cCode;
  char *cName;
  char *cDescription;
  studentID *registered[8];
  studentID *waitlisted[12];
  int studentRegistered;
  int studentWaitlisted;
}course;

course courses[3];


#endif
```

Printing the values of the registered students works fine, but when I print the waitlisted students I get a segmentation error. I used gdb and found it was on this line but couldn't figure out why:

```
printf("%d - %s, %s \n", courses[0].waitlisted[i]->num.studentNum, courses[0].waitlisted[i]->lastName, courses[0].waitlisted[i]->firstName);
```

Comment: `waitlisted[i]` point to something? You have to post how you initialize these `struct variables`

Comment: @coderredoc I've initialized them in the header file as shown

Comment: Essentially the `waitlisted` variable is the exact same setup and function as the `registered` variable but for some reason the `waitlisted` one causes the segmentation error

Comment: You are using a bunch of pointers there. I believe that you didn't malloc properly all those fields. Could you share how you initialize your course arrays?

Comment: @Dlacreme I've added the rest of the courses.c file, these two files are the only two accessing the structs

Comment: use `gdb` to examine the variables when it crashes

Comment: OT - no point in looping once. Unless thats just a placeholder for looping more than once (doesnt look like it since `j` isnt used in the loop), ditch the `for (j = 0; j < 1; j++)` loops

Answer (score 0):

`studentID *waitlisted[12];` That means they will hold the address of variable of type structure `studentID`. You simply didn't do this but start to access those pointer variables. You have passed them to `scanf` which invokes undefined behavior due to trying to read an unintialized pointer variable.

So what you need to do here -

```
courses[i].waitlisted = malloc(sizeof *courses[i].waitlisted * courses[i].studentWaitlisted);
```

Same goes for the `studentID` also. Here `fistName` is a `char*` you need to allocate some meory to access it otherwise it's UB.

Or

```
typedef struct{
  char firstName[100]; //you are considering that name length would be 100
                       //at max.
  char lastName[100];
  studentNumber num;
}studentID;
```

---

#### After OP edited question:

The seg fault you get is because of accessing a local variable after it's lifetime ended.

```
courses[0].cCode = courseCode;
```

What you can do is

```
courses[0].cCode = strdup(courseCode);
```

Initialize array `int numbers[999]={0};` otherwise you might access garbage value as the indexing is result of random number geneartion.

```
if( random < 999){
    numbers[random] = numbers[numbersLeft-1];
    numbersLeft--;
}
else{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error" );
}
```

Lots of repeated code. You should remove repeated code. And also there is no need for `single-iteration-for-loop`.

Comment: I don't follow, if theyre uninitialized then how does the lines above with the regular `registered` students not create the same problem. How would I initialize them otherwise?

Comment: `courses.c:222:29: error: assignment to expression with array type

  courses[i].waitlisted = malloc(sizeof *courses[i].waitlisted *courses[i].studentWaitlisted);
`
is the error I get when trying to malloc it. But I hadn't considered mallocing it because isn't malloc only necessary for dynamic arrays?

Comment: @JackLoveday.: You have *earlier posted a code which was completely different* from this. If you are assigning `waitlisted[i]=&student[j]` then it would work.

Comment: Yes I changed the code to add in the wait list, otherwise it's not too much different. All I'm trying to understand is why can I print and access the registered students but not the waitlisted ones. It has the same declarations and set up, here see the output as well:

`CS722 - Web Programming: Learn the language of HTML, and how to create websites.
Registered Students (6/6):
* 65137 - Smith, Emma
* 96239 - Williams, Olivia
* 79581 - Brown, Noah
* 11072 - Miller, Logan
* 89990 - Davis, Sophia
* 58426 - Loveday, Jack
Waitlisted Students (0)
`

Comment: vs a run where there is a waitlist:
`CS068 - Web Programming: Learn the language of HTML, and how to create websites.
Registered Students (4/4):
* 60648 - Williams, Olivia
* 90546 - Johnson, Liam
* 58788 - Miller, Logan
* 11102 - Davis, Sophia
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`

Comment: @JackLoveday.: Wait as you have provided code will answer..just give me some hour. I will get back when I am a bit less busy

Comment: I appreciate that